# Why do I get the weird purple line in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

my code is below. It should replicate. This is code for downloading the data, wrangling the data, building the loess line and then adding the graph.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(macleish)
library(lubridate)

mydata <- whately_2015
mydata <- whately_2015 %>% 
  dplyr::select(temperature, when) %>%
  mutate(when = as_date(mydata$when), temperature = temperature * (9/5)+32)

mydata$seasons <- as.character(c(rep("Winter", 11232), rep("Spring", 24624-11232), rep("Summer", 38161-24624), rep("Autumn", 50976-38161), rep("Winter", 52560-50976)))

start_dates <- mdy(c("03/20/2015","06/21/2015", "09/23/2015", "12/21/2015"))
end_dates <- mdy(c("03/19/2015", "06/20/2015", "09/22/2015", "12/20/2015", "12/31/2015"))
Season = c("Spring Equinox- 3/20", "Summer Solstice- 6/21", "Autumn Equinox- 9/23", "Winter Solstice- 12/21")
start_dates_gg <- mdy(c( "01/01/2015", "03/20/2015","06/21/2015", "09/30/2015"))
Season_gg = c("Winter Solstice- 12/21", "Spring Equinox- 3/20", "Summer Solstice- 6/21", "Autumn Equinox- 9/23")

mydata$datenum <- as.numeric(mydata$when)
model10 <- loess(temperature ~ datenum, data=mydata, span = 0.10)
mydata$smoothed10 <- predict(model10)

ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=when)) +
 geom_line(aes(y=smoothed10, col=seasons)) +
  theme_bw() +
  annotate(geom="text", x=start_dates_gg, y=c(10, 27, 75, 60), label=Season_gg, hjust=0, col = c("#C77Cff","#7CAE00","#00BFC4","#F8766D")) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  labs(title = "Weather and Seasons", x = "Date", y= "Temperature (F)")
```

I get a weird graph that looks like this. Why the weird purple line running across the screen? The purple line is just meant for the Winter season.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `group = 1` to your `geom_line()` call to let `ggplot` know that all the points belong together and should be connected with a single line.

```r
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = when)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = smoothed10, col = seasons, group = 1)) + # add group here
  theme_bw() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = start_dates_gg, y = c(10, 27, 75, 60), 
           label = Season_gg, hjust = 0, col = c("#C77Cff", "#7CAE00", "#00BFC4", "#F8766D")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(title = "Weather and Seasons", x = "Date", y = "Temperature (F)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a `colour` mapping, by default `ggplot` will connect all points with the same colour. You can stop that by providing an additional `group` mapping that specifies which points should be connected, e.g.:

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=when)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=smoothed10, col=seasons, group = lubridate::year(when))) +
    theme_bw() +
    annotate(geom="text", x=start_dates_gg, y=c(10, 27, 75, 60), label=Season_gg, 
             hjust=0, col = c("#C77Cff","#7CAE00","#00BFC4","#F8766D")) + 
    theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
    labs(title = "Weather and Seasons", x = "Date", y= "Temperature (F)")
```